# Webpack HTML minifier is removing CMS {variables} from CSS rules

Tags: html, css, webpack, minify, html-webpack-plugin

I need help with html-minimizer-webpack-plugin. Right now, when I write this:

```
<style>
.video__embed {
aspect-ratio: {video_width}/{video_height} !important; 
padding-top: 0 !important;
}
</style>
```

minifier removes `{video_width}/{video_height}!important; padding-top: 0 !important;`, resulting in

`<style>.video__embed{aspect-ratio:{};}</style>`

How can I configure the plugin to keep those values intact, but still minified?

Comment: The html-minimizer-web pack-plugin does not support variables. Can you try with this plugin *postcss-preset-env* (https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-preset-env).

Comment: How is it you're minifying CMS content? As yang zhou states below, only valid (compiled) CSS should be minified.

Answer (score 1):

```xml
aspect-ratio: {video_width}/{video_height} !important;
```

This is not a valid CSS syntax. I think you should transpile this to valid CSS before use minimizer.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, not possible in my scenario.